# Uninstalling grub after dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I tried to dual-boot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with my pre-installed copy of Windows 10, but couldn't get it to work. Decided to delete the Ubuntu partition but I'm unable to uninstall grub completely.

Usually Windows 10 boots normally. But when the system wakes from hibernation(or dead battery), I'm greeted with the grub2 command line interface. Restarting the laptop lets Windows bootloader take charge again & boot normally.

I tried these things, but they had no effect:

- `bootrec /fixmbr`, `/fixboot`, `\rebuildbcd` all run successfully
  but do not solve the problem.
- Ran `sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr` from the Ubuntu live USB
- "Write MBR" via EasyBCD (not sure it was relevant but tried    nevertheless)
- A tutorial suggested I removed the grub files altogether by mounting the EFI partition. Now waking after hibernation takes me to an "insert disk" screen; rebooting lets me use Windows again.

To summarize, Windows bootloader doesn't take charge when waking from hibernation but overrides grub otherwise. (This was the same issue I was encountering before uninstalling Ubuntu)

I finally installed Ubuntu to a USB instead. Made sure I selected the correct drive to install the bootloader. Aaaaand grub command-line is back. What's going on and how do I get Windows to boot normally?

Comment: Grub is a boot manager.  It doesn't take up a lot of space on the drive.  You don't uninstall a boot manager.  You replace it with a different one.  What is your main objective?

Comment: Did you use backslash in `bootrec` calls? There should be a `/`.

Comment: @James, this is interfering with my normal booting, I need windows bootloader to run normally. As a side goal, given my previous issues, I'd like to remove traces of the previous installation if I'm doing a fresh install.

Comment: @Melebius, sorry for mistyping that here, edited now.  I ran it with `/` and it appeared to complete successfully.

Comment: Probably UEFI-install, so fixmbr will not fix anything. Check boot-order in UEFI-BIOS and change boot-order to Windows if possible.

Comment: Yes, it's UEFI. I changed boot order to load USB first but no good. It just took slightly longer and then went ahead with the same behavior.

Comment: What I find strange is that after I reinstalled Ubuntu (& bootloader) on the external USB, grub is still on my main HDD (`ls` lists only `(hd0)` partitions). Am i missing something?

Comment: Grub-EFI is installed in the ESP (EFI System Partition) of the first drive (sda) by default.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old, but I came across it in my own search when trying to solve this problem for myself, and I found a solution that worked for me when none of the other answers had so I needed to share!

I had dual-booted Ubuntu on my laptop alongside Windows 10. I decided to remove Ubuntu, and had deleted it's partition, but grub still kept interrupting my boot loader. After trying numerous suggestions left on forums, I finally just came across an insanely simple, and graphical way to remove it on my own lol. (So, disclaimer, I have no idea if any other versions of Windows has this option or not)

But all I did was **F12** while the computer was booting to get into the boot options. And under *Other Options* I selected **BIOS Setup**. On the left-hand side I selected **Boot Sequence** and right there it listed my different boot options, and I could select them to change their order or remove them or whatever I wanted. All I had to do was make sure only "ubuntu" was marked, and then I clicked **Delete Boot** and exited. It continued to the log-in screen and I restarted my laptop just to double check it solved my problem and it had!

Answer (score 0):

I think the bootrec\fixmbr 
only works for MBR partitions where MBR stored at beggining of HDD. In your case you have GPT ( since you have EFI partition )
Why don't you try Mounting and Deleting Ubuntu & related grub manually from EFI partition and then Using a bootable copy of windows , Do an automatic repair.

If you dont have a bootable disk use SuperGrubDisk to boot into Windows.

else I think your BIOS/UEFI will have a OS-bootmanager under boot. If you do, then there defenetly will be a Windows option, move it up accrose the list to set its priority highest.

Ubuntu installs well but Uninstalling is incomplete.

(Sorry If I'm not helpful as Its my first answer and I'm not too familiar with EFI)